# Template method of template class specialization

Tags: c++, linux, templates, g++

Here is my code:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> class MyClass
{
public:
    template<int num> static int DoSomething();
};

template<typename T1, typename T2> template<int num> int MyClass<T1, T2>::DoSomething()
{
    cout << "This is the common method" << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(T1) = " << sizeof(T1) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(T2) = " << sizeof(T2) << endl;
    return num;
}
```

It works well. But when I try to add this

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> template<> int MyClass<T1, T2>::DoSomething<0>()
{
    cout << "This is ZERO!!!" << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(T1) = " << sizeof(T1) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(T2) = " << sizeof(T2) << endl;
    return num;
}
```

I get compiller errors:
invalid explicit specialization before «>» token
template-id «DoSomething<0>» for «int MyClass::DoSomething()» does not match any template declaration

I use g++ 4.6.1
What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't specialise a template that's a member of a class template, without specialising the outer template:

> C++11 14.7.3/16: In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized, **except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well**.

I think your best option is to add the extra parameter to `MyClass`, and then partially specialise that.

Comment: But the example is not explicitly specialising a class member template - it's specialising a function member template. So the part you have highlighted doesn't apply and the permission given in the previous part of the sentence seems to apply.

Comment: @AlanStokes: "Class member template" means a template that's a member of a class - it could be a template for either a function or a nested class. "Member class template" would specifically refer to a class template that's a member (per the use of that term in 14.7.3/1). GCC, at least, uses that interpretation.

Comment: 14.5.2/1 suggests a template that's a member of a class is just a "member template". "class member template" doesn't seem to be a defined term. Yuck. But it looks like [DR 529](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#529) will clarify this to agree with your answer.

Comment: Does anyone know why this is? I've found a bunch of explanations that just explain that you can't do it, but no mention of any rational.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know,

but I stumbled uppon the same problem in my current project and found a workaround which does the job at least for template arguments which are no types but values (like `template <int num>`).

The implementation of my solution:

```
template<class T> template<int num> void Classname<T>::methodname()
{
    if (num == 0)
    {
        //implementation for num == 0
    }
    else if (num == 1)
    {
        //implementation for num == 1
    }
    //more cases...
}
```

`num == constant` will evaluate to a  constant expression so the compiler will optimize your code to just keep the correct implementation for each case.

Please correct me if I'm wrong or if something makes this a bad solution ;)

Comment: Oh we just needed 2 separate templates... not combined.

Answer (score 0):

That is sad but true: **you cannot explicitly specialize a class template unless its enclosing class templates are also explicitly specialized**. For more information you may read

- this comp.lang.c++.moderated thread [Class Template Specializations](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_frm/thread/d3cf73585cd4548a?hl=sv&lr&rnum=2&prev=/groups?q=Enclosing%2bdo_foo&hl=sv&btnG=Google-s%25C3%25B6kning&pli=1)
- or this article: [Explicit Specialization of Members of Class Templates](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/language/ref/clrc16explicit_spec_members.htm)

Below I've specialized MyClass first and everything got done.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T1, typename T2> class MyClass
{
public:
  template<int num> static int DoSomething();
};

template<typename T1, typename T2> template<int num> int MyClass<T1, T2>::DoSomething()
{
  cout << "This is the common method" << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(T1) = " << sizeof(T1) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(T2) = " << sizeof(T2) << endl;
  return num;
}

template<> template<> int MyClass<char, int>::DoSomething<0>()
{
  cout << "This is ZERO!!!" << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(T1) = " << sizeof(char) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(T2) = " << sizeof(int) << endl;
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  MyClass<char, int> m;
  m.DoSomething<2>();
  m.DoSomething<0>();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
This is the common method
sizeof(T1) = 1
sizeof(T2) = 4
This is ZERO!!!
sizeof(T1) = 1
sizeof(T2) = 4
```

---

EUREKA! This works well on MSVCPP 10.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T1, typename T2> class MyClass
{
public:
  template<int num> static int DoSomething();
  template<> static int DoSomething<0>() {
    cout << "This is ZERO!!!" << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(T1) = " << sizeof(T1) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(T2) = " << sizeof(T2) << endl;
    return 0;
  }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2> template<int num> int MyClass<T1, T2>::DoSomething()
{
  cout << "This is the common method" << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(T1) = " << sizeof(T1) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(T2) = " << sizeof(T2) << endl;
  return num;
}

int main() {
  MyClass<char, int> m;
  m.DoSomething<2>();
  m.DoSomething<0>();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
This is the common method
sizeof(T1) = 1
sizeof(T2) = 4
This is ZERO!!!
sizeof(T1) = 1
sizeof(T2) = 4
```

BTW, do not `return num;` from specialization. It doesn't ever know what `num` is.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ok. But it does on MSVCPP 10.

Comment: @DaddyM: MSVC does not force some of the standard rules. Especially with template programming this sucks. I always write the complicated template parts in MingW, if it compiles then move it to MSVC.

Comment: MSVC has an extension for in-class member specialization

Answer (score 0):

Similar to DocValle answer, not to rely on possible compiler optimisation

you could use constexpr if to enforce compile time branching

```
template<class T> template<int num> void Classname<T>::methodname()
{
    if constexpr (num == 0)
    {
        //implementation for num == 0
    }
    else if constexpr (num == 1)
    {
        //implementation for num == 1
    }
    //more cases...
}
```