# Out-of-line constructor for nested class when outer class is templated

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, inner-classes

I'm having a heck of a time trying to provide an out-of-line constructor for a nested class when the outer class has template parameters. The twist is the inner class only differs by data member declarations. Below is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My apologies if it could be more minimal.

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

template<class W, bool B>
struct F
{
    struct G;
};

template class F<int, false>;
template class F<long, true>;

template<>
struct F<int, false>::G
{
    G();
    byte b[4];
};

template<>
struct F<long, true>::G
{
    G();
    byte b[6];
};

template<>
F<int, false>::G::G()
{
    b[0] = b[1] = b[2] = b[3] = 0;
}

template<>
F<long, true>::G::G()
{
    b[0] = b[1] = b[2] = b[3] = b[4] = b[5] = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

From above, I simply want `F::G::G` to be out of line.

When I attempt to compile it, it results in:

```
test.cxx:29:1: error: template-id ‘G<>’ for ‘F<int, false>::G::G()’ does not match any template declaration
 F<int, false>::G::G()
 ^
test.cxx:35:1: error: template-id ‘G<>’ for ‘F<long int, true>::G::G()’ does not match any template declaration
 F<long, true>::G::G()
 ^
```

How do I provide an out-of-line constructor for `G`?

---

There are other similar questions that focus on functions. My disconnect seems to be getting this working when the data member is the sore spot.

- [How to explicitly instantiate a template class that has a nested class with a friend function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12875679)
- [Template method of template class specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9276389)
- [Specialization of template method in partial class specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9232758)
- et al.

---

Here's what I am trying to do. C++ does not allow it to be this easy, so I had to resort to template specializations to get the compile time declarations.

```
template<class W, bool B>
struct F
{
    struct G
    {
    #if (B == true)
        byte b[6];
    #else
        byte b[4];
    #endif
    };
};
```

Comment: Removing the `template<>` from the definitions of the `G` constructors [works for me](http://ideone.com/u65mFa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though G is an inner class of a template class, it's not actually itself a template class.

This will work:

```
F<int, false>::G::G()
{
    b[0] = b[1] = b[2] = b[3] = 0;
}

F<long, true>::G::G()
{
    b[0] = b[1] = b[2] = b[3] = b[4] = b[5] = 0;
}
```

of course in this case, you could save yourself the bother of worrying about constructors:

```
template<>
struct F<int, false>::G
{
    byte b[4] = { 0 };  // zero - initialised
};

template<>
struct F<long, true>::G
{
    byte b[6] = { 0 }; // zero - initialised
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually went the other way - trying to further template `G`, and C++ silliness like `template<> template<> ...`. I could scream at how much time I wasted on that....