# Template specializations for inner class

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-specialization

consider the following code :

```
struct X
{
    template <typename T>
    class Y
    {};
 };
template<>
class X::Y<double>{
};
```

here we are specializing the Y class for the type double and the code works fine. the problem is that if I change the code to this:

```
template<typename A>
struct X
{
    template <typename T>
    class Y
    {};
 };
template<typename A>
class X<A>::Y<double>{
};
```

the compiler will report an error:

> 'X::Y': explicit specialization is using partial
>   specialization syntax, use template <> instead!

dose any one know how can I specialize class Y in this case?

Comment: Does doing what the error message says not help? Use `template<>` instead of `template<typename A>` on the nested template specialization.

Comment: it dosen't work ! i tired this as well:           
template<>
class X::Y<double>{
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer - you can't fully specialize templated inner class of templated outer class. But if you really want to achieve similar effect you could try partial specialization with dummy defaulted template parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A>
struct X
{
    template <typename T, T* =nullptr>
    class Y{};
 };

template<typename A>
template<double *Ptr>
class X<A>::Y<double, Ptr> {
public:
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << X<int>::Y<double>::value << std::endl;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OrbN42Iv8OSCHVAm)

Comment: the book :Advanced metaprogramming in classic c++, on page 33 says:
Template specializations are valid only at the namespace level:
struct X
{
template <typename T>
class Y
{};
template <> // illegal, but usually tolerated by compilers
class Y<double>
{};
};
template <> // legal
class X::Y<double>
{
};
   so what you have done might work but not always !

Comment: @MEMS You're author might be right. After looking for standards examples I've realized I might been actually over-interpreting the `[temp.class.spec] /5`. Updating code

Comment: @MEMS according to C++ Standard Core Language Active Issues `727. In-class explicit specializations` inline partial specialization of member class is well formed... so my previous code was indeed valid. Please find the [reference](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#727)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot specialize an inner template class without explicitly specializing the outer one as well. [See this question for more details and a quote from the standard.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276389/template-method-of-template-class-specialization)

**Workaround:** create an outer class that takes both `T` and `A` in a detail namespace, and alias it inside `X`:

```
namespace impl
{
    template <typename A, typename T>
    struct Y { };
}

template<typename A>
struct X
{
    template <typename T>
    using Y = impl::Y<A, T>;
};
```

---

If you are fine with explicitly specializing both inner and outer class, you can use the following syntax:

```
template <>
template <>
class X<int>::Y<double>
{
    // ...
};
```

[**Example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5QsXzayEWYB8Vz1E)

Comment: what if I want to specialize it for specific X and Y like: 
template <>
class X<double>::Y<double>{
};
 in this case it also complains! it says: error C2992: 'X<double>::Y<double>': invalid or missing template parameter list

Comment: @MEMS: you need double `template<>`. [Example on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5QsXzayEWYB8Vz1E).

Comment: Updated my answer as well.